# In .htaccess, recode /@handle to ?@handle

Tags: apache, .htaccess, url, https

How do I recode the forward slash / to /? :

```
https://www.myserver.com/@handle1  -->  https://www.myserver.com/?@handle1 

-OR-

https://www.myserver.com/@handle1  -->  https://www.myserver.com?@handle1
```

So the rule for .htaccess is something with taking a @ and mapping it to /?@ instead -- or the first slash / mapped to /? .

We are trying to implement handles in a mature web application.

Thanks for any help here.

Comment: A "@" is pretty exotic in a URL, but I don't see a reason why you can't simply implement a standard rewriting rule which does what you ask for. Have you tried that? Please add your attempt to the question and explain what happened, so why you were not satisfied with that attempt.

Comment: Thanks this seems to work:   RewriteEngine on
 
RewriteRule ^@(.*) ?@$1 [R]

Comment: Thanks for the help -- was overthinking this!

Comment: @NYCTech You should add that as an answer (and later "accept" it). However, that rule won't work unless you also have a `RewriteBase` directive defined. You are also missing the `L` flag. However, should this be a "redirect" (as you have there) or an internal "rewrite" (I would have thought the later)? _Aside:_ `https://www.myserver.com?@handle1` is not strictly valid; there is always a slash at the start of the URL-path.